# Radius of convergence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{1+x^n} $

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

I want to prove that the radius of convergence of the series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{1+x^n} $$

is $r=1$. Yeah in this interval does converge by comparison with the geo series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n $.

But how to prove it?

**Addendum:**
For $x \in (-1, 1)$ we see that the series converges absolutely:
$$\left | \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{1+x^n} \right |\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left | \frac{x^n}{1+x^n} \right |\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x|^n$$

and for $x>1$ the function inside the series goes to $1$ instead of $0$ hence it does not converge. But how to prove that the same holds for $x<-1$?

Comment: Well you can see that the series diverge when $x>1$ since then the terms tend to $1$ and not to $0$.So that would be the prove since you compared it already with the geometric series

Comment: @kingW3 should not I also take the case $x<-1$?

Comment: I just updated the question adding the details.

Comment: Same logic applies to $x<-1$,you have that the terms go to 1

Comment: Hmm.. point is I don't see it... could you add some details?

Comment: Consider instead of writing $x^n$ for $x\in(-\infty,-1)$ consider writing $(-x)^n$ for $x\in(1,\infty)$,can you show that the term $\frac{(-x)^n}{1+(-x)^n}$ tends to 1 when $n$ tends to infinity?

Comment: I think that by first changing that $-x$ to $u$ then this goes to $1$. No?

Comment: I think I got it.. thank you!

Comment: "radius of convergence" is a concept for power series, but this isn't a power series.

Comment: @Tolaso Are you saying $\left | \frac{x^n}{1+x^n} \right |\leq |x|^n$ for all $n \geq 1$ and $-1 < x < 0$?

Answer (score 0):

If $x<-1$, then $|x|^n \pm 1 > 0$ and $|x|^n \to \infty$ as $n$ grows.

$$f_n(x) \,=\,  \frac{(-|x|)^n}{(-|x|)^n+1} \,=\,  \frac{|x|^n}{|x|^n+(-1)^n} \,>\, 0.$$

$$\frac{1}{f_n(x)} \,=\,   \frac{|x|^n+(-1)^n}{|x|^n}\,=\, 1+  \frac{(-1)^n}{|x|^n} \to 1.$$

Therefore the general term $f_n(x) \to 1$ with $n$, so $\sum f_n(x)$ cannot converge when $x<-1$.

For the absolute convergence when $-1<x<1$, note that $0 \leq |x|^n < 1$ and $|x|^n \to 0$ as $n$ grows. For all large enough $n$,

$$\left |f_n(x)\right | \,=\,  \frac{  |x|^n  }{|1+x^n|} \,\leq\, \frac{  |x|^n  }{1-|x|^n}\,\leq\, \frac{  |x|^n  }{\frac{1}{2}}.$$

We know $\sum 2|x|^n < \infty$. Hence

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left | f_n(x)\right | \,=\,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left | \frac{x^n}{1+x^n} \right | < \infty$$

holds also.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2434674/688046