# Showing that the complex series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{1+z^n}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Show the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{1+z^n}$$ converges absolutely and uniformly in $$\{z: |z|\le r\}$$ for $r<1$.

Can I use the M-test here and does uniform convergence imply absolute convergence?

Comment: Yes on the M-test, and no, uniform convergence does not imply absolute convergence.

Comment: To use $M$-test: $$|z^n/(1+z^n)|\le r^n/(1-r^n)$$ and to give an example where uniform convergence holds but absolute convergence fails: let $f_n(z)\equiv \frac1n,\forall z\in\Bbb C$, then $\sum_n(-1)^nf(z)$ converges uniformly on $\Bbb C$ but not absolutely at any point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left|\frac{z^n }{1+z^n}\right|\leq \frac{|z|^n }{1-|z|^n}\leq\frac{r^n}{1-r}$$

But $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{r^n}{1-r} =1$$
therefore by Weierstrass test the series converges uniformly and absolutely in the set $$\{z: |z|\leq r\}.$$